# Convergence in normed spaces

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

I consider a sequence of elements $\{f_n\}_n$ in a normed space $X$ such as $\Vert f_n-f\Vert_X\to 0, n\to\infty$. Let $\{Q_n\}_n$ a complex sequence with $Q_n\to Q$ as $n\to\infty$.
Does $Q_nf_n$ converge to $Qf$ in $X$?
I can write
$$\Vert Q_nf_n-Qf\Vert_X=\Vert Q_nf_n-Qf_n+Qf_n-Qf\Vert_X\leq$$
$$\leq \Vert f_n\Vert_X\vert Q_n-Q\vert+|Q|\Vert f_n-f\Vert_X$$
and I have the thesis.

Answer (score 1):

You still have to show that $||f_n||_X$ is bounded. If it blows up, then your first term will not go to zero.

Comment: But by continuity of norm $\Vert f_n\Vert\to\Vert f\Vert$

Comment: A norm convergent sequence is necessarily bounded.

Comment: Yes, it's not hard to show, but it should be mentioned.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to underline this fact in my post; it can be seen as a consequence of  "principle of uniform boundedness".